# How to change to local video player on shortcode ultimate to video.js?

Tags: shortcode, video-player

I have [Shortcodes Ultimate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/) plugin, and I would like to change this plugin video player to [Video.js player](http://www.videojs.com/).
That's becouse, the original player is very afful, and instabil, and you can't control volume, can't replay the video,so this player very insufficient.
I can't use the original wordpress player,becouse the plugin use the same short code as the wordpress short code and this do a little conflict.
Example for the plugin shortcode:

```
[video url="http://www.neocsatblog.mblx.hu/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Cas-és-a-sex.mp4" poster="http://www.neocsatblog.mblx.hu/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/not-bad.png" title="Castiel találkozása a szex-el"]
```

I can't delete this plugin,becouse I use some usefull function in here.
So the bestway be if I can change the video player to Video.js player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to re-register the default WordPress `[video]` shortcode:

```
/**
 * Re-Register the default [video] shortcode
 * WPSE: 120057
 */
function wpse_120057()
{
    add_shortcode( 'video', 'wp_video_shortcode' );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpse_120057' );
```

Here is the [file](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/shortcodes-ultimate/trunk/inc/core/class.data.php) in the *Shortcodes Ultimate* plugin that contains the `[video]` shortcode registration.

Comment: Okey but,may be better if i can use video.js,thats becouse,this is a best player witch I ever   see.

Comment: Have you tried to install the [video.js plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/videojs-html5-video-player-for-wordpress/) and use `[videojs]` ?

Comment: No,but thanks, I try it now,give me a second.

Comment: Yeah,this work fine thanks!
Any idea how to add cc function for this?

Comment: ok great (please mark the question as solved)